# ODE: $u'' +\frac {(1-4z)}{z^2(1-2z)}u' =0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have got the following ODE:
$$u'' +\frac {(1-4z)}{z^2(1-2z)}u' =0$$
The answer book rearranges as follows:
$$\frac{u''}{u'} = -\frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)}$$

I know I have to split the fraction on the RHS. But what is happening on the LHS:$\frac{u''}{u'}$
Can this be integrated at once?

Comment: It's also enough to set $w = u'$ and solve as a first order linear DE

Comment: @Kaynex: can you explain more? I can't see why this is enough?

Comment: With $v:=u'$, this reads $\dfrac{v'}v$, which is the derivative of $\ln v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\frac{u''}{u'}$ is the logarithmic derivative of $u'$ $$\mathcal{L (u')}=\frac{u''}{u'}$$
You can also susbtitute $p=u' \implies u''=p'$

Then
$$\frac{u''}{u'} = -\frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)}$$
$$\frac{dp}{pdz} = -\frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)}$$
$$\int \frac{dp}{p} = -\int \frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)} dz$$
$$\ln ( p) = -\int \frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)} dz+K$$
$$\ln ( u') = -\int \frac{1-4z}{z^2(1-2z)} dz+K$$

or write 
$$\frac{u''}{u'}=\frac{du'}{u'dz}$$
and integrate the separable equation.....

Comment: by using the substitution, in fact it becomes a first order DE? Then you substitute back. And after that: you could write: for the LHS (and RHS with his own exp): $e^{\ln u'} = u'$

Comment: yes @JoeGoldiamond it becomes a first order because you dont have $u$ alone your equation only has derivatives of u

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$[\ln u']'=\frac{u''}{u'}$$

Comment: Of course! Chain rule. I was continuously looking for a analogy with $ u'' - cu' =p$ and  using standard way to solution.